# post default values when using FormUrlEncoded in Retrofit API

Tags: android, retrofit2

Here is my Retrofit API Interface

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST(/test.php)
Call<List<RetrofitModel>> function1(
@Field("type")String type,
@Field("name")String name,
@Field("sex")String sex);
```

when I am use this

```
mRetrofitAPI.function1("type1","toco","female").enqueue(new Callback<List<RetrofitModel>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<List<RetrofitModel>> call, @NonNull Response<List<RetrofitModel>> response) { }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<List<RetrofitModel>> call, @NonNull Throwable t) { }
});
```

The problem is Even though I know that "type1" is going to be there, I have to put the same value("type1") on the type field every time.

---

Can it POST with default fields like this?

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST(/test.php)
Call<List<RetrofitModel>> function1(
@Field("type")String "type1",
@Field("name")String name,
@Field("sex")String sex);
```

or

```
@POST
@DefaultField("type" = "type1")
Call<List<RetrofitModel>> function1(@Field("anotherParams")String anotherParams)
```

for

```
mRetrofitAPI.function1("toco","female").enqueue(new Callback<List<RetrofitModel>>() {
```

Comment: In kotlin you can specify the default values for parameters and you can just pass the value which required rest it will take the default value.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use List in response

use another model like this:

```
public class RetrofitModelResponse {
private List<RetrofitModel> retrofitModelList;

public List<RetrofitModel> getRetrofitModelList() {
    return retrofitModelList;
}

public void setRetrofitModelList(List<RetrofitModel> retrofitModelList) {
    this.retrofitModelList = retrofitModelList;
}
```

}

Use this as a retrofitResponse model